# Converting FindScanline assembly code to purepascal

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-5, delphi-xe7

I am trying to convert some Delphi 5 code to Delphi XE7-x64 and I am stuck on following code:

```
function FindScanline(Source : Pointer; MaxLen : Cardinal;
  Value : Cardinal) : Cardinal; assembler;
asm
          PUSH    ECX
          MOV     ECX,EDX
          MOV     EDX,EDI
          MOV     EDI,EAX
          POP     EAX
          REPE    SCASB
          MOV     EAX,ECX
          MOV     EDI,EDX
end;
```

As far as I understand following things are occuring:

```
push the contents of ECX register(Value) onto the stack
move contents of EDX register(MaxLen) into ECX register. now ECX holds (MaxLen)
move contents of EDI register into EDX register. now EDX holds (EDI) 
move contents of EAX register into EDI register. now EDI holds (Source)
pop ECX into EDX. now EDX holds (Value). Was (EDI) lost?
repeat while equal ?decrement ECX for each char?
move contents of ECX register into EAX register
move contents of EDX register into EDI register
```

For reference function [FindScanline](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/tests/archive/jvcl/source/JvHints.pas#L168) is used in function [GetCursorHeightMargin](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/tests/archive/jvcl/source/JvHints.pas#L157)

Any help in translating above will be appreciated.

Comment: You should always **add** the generic [tag:delphi] tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a literal translation:

```
function FindScanline(Source: Pointer; MaxLen: Cardinal; Value: Cardinal): Cardinal;
var
  Ptr: PByte;
begin
  Result := MaxLen;
  if Result > 0 then
    dec(Result);
  Ptr := Source;
  while (Result > 0) and (Ptr^ = Value) do
  begin
    inc(Ptr);
    dec(Result);
  end;
end;
```

It's rather messy to handle the edge cases unfortunately.

Comment: You Sir are great  _/\\_